# Finding minimum distance from a large parity check matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

Let $C$ be the linear code that has parity check matrix formed from all possible columns of weight 3 and length 5. We want to show that $d_{H}(C)=4$.

My first instinct would be to show that $d_{H}(C)\geq 4$ by showing no set of $3$ columns sum to $0$, but this would require $10 \choose 3$ checks, so is obviously unfeasible.

Comment: "formed from all columns of weight 3 and length 5" Does that mean that all its columns have weight 3 or that it has all the possible vectors of weight 3?

Comment: @leonbloy The columns are all possible vectors of weight 3 with length 5. Apologies for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> showing no set of $3$ columns sum to $0$, but this would require $10 \choose 3$ checks, so is obviously unfeasible.

Actually, that's the way. Assume that there exists such three columns : $a + b + c = 0 \implies a+b=c$

But that's impossible:

Let $t$ be the positions where $a$ and $b$ have an one in common. Then $w(a+b)=w(a)+w(b)-2 t = 6 -2t$ which is even for any $t$. Then $w(c) \ne 3$.

Of course, you must also discard the case where there are less that 3 columns that sum to $0$, but that's easy.

Comment: Aha, thank you very much!